# AngularJS and database connection in JAVA

Tags: angularjs

Can I connect my AngularJS based application to Oracle database with the help of JAVA?
I am using JAVA for backend, so need to connect AngularJS code to Database which is in oracle and I am using sql developer to access data.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, yes you can.
Angular relies on RESTful Web services for requesting and storing data. You can use the [Spring Framework](http://spring.io/) to create RESTful web services and through the POST/GET calls you can send data and retrieve data. You need to have a RESTful web service. You can say that Angular needs RESTful Web Service.

That's really is the beauty of Angular JS. Implemention of RESTful WEB Service depends on you. It can be in any technology stack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you need a RESTful Web Service.

On your .js do like that:

```
app.controller('AppName', function($scope, $http){ 
   $scope.datas = [];   

   $http.get('URI from Web Service')
   .success(function(retorno){                            
      $scope.datas = retorno.msg;
   })
   .error(function(error){
      console.log(error); 
   }); 
});
```